# Disqus Comment count does not refresh

Tags: javascript, disqus

I placed the Disqus comment count in two separate places on my website (Home and Post Pages). First time I load the pages the comment count are shown correctly. However, I start to add new comments to test it and the comments count are stick to an old state and the comments count start to be different on my home page and my post page, even if I delete the cache on the browser, the call returns always different and not updated value for each page. I don't know if I am doing something wrong.

My configuration variables are:

```
  /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES * * */
var disqus_shortname = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"]';
var disqus_identifier = '@Model.Href(Url)';
var disqus_url = 'http://localhost:31048' + disqus_identifier;
 var disqus_developer = 1;
```

the values of these variable are (for a specific post):

@Model.Href(Url): **/Archive/2015/2/entryyy_points_for_commands**
@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"]: **webtestin**

My anchor element for showing total commnents is (it is the same both pages):

```
 <a href="@string.Format("{0}#disqus_thread", Model.Href(Url))"></a>
```

it produces this html anchor element:

```
 "<a href="/Archive/2015/2/entryyy_points_commands#disqus_thread">5 Comments</a>"
```

I can see one js (count-data.js)f ile returned with the call with these values (id value url is a bit odd):

```
                var DISQUSWIDGETS;

            if (typeof DISQUSWIDGETS != 'undefined') {
                DISQUSWIDGETS.displayCount({"text":{"and":"and","comments":{"zero":"0 Comments","multiple":"{num} Comments","one":"1 Comment"}},"counts":[{"id":"http:\/\/localhost:31048\/Archive\/2015\/2\/entryyy_points_for_aspnet5_commands","comments":4}]});
            }
```